# Route to the view received by Node.js request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, npm

Controller code:

```
bina: function(req, res) {
  var request = require('request');

  request({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/bina/',
    method: 'GET',
  }, function(err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      var data = JSON.parse(res.body);
      console.log(data);
      res.render(data)
    }
  })
}
```

The data that comes with the request does not see any functions like `res.view` or `res.render`.

Error output:

```
res.render(data)
           ^
TypeError: res.render is not a function
```

Note:

I can see the data via `console.log(data)` via web service. I use Sail.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you are doing wrong:

You are using same variable (**res**) name twice. And at the res.render it taking the one which is in the nearest scope. I have renamed the **res => to response** and now it should work.

```
bina: function(req, res) {
    var request = require('request');

    request({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/bina/',
        method: 'GET',

    }, function (err, response, body) { // Changed the variable name
            if (err) {

                console.log(err);

            }
            else {
                var data = JSON.parse(response.body);
                console.log(data);
                res.render(data)

            }
        })
}
```

Hope it solved your issue.